# How to replace an existing json value with a new json?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to compare every name of `$str1` with every name of `$str2`.
If a name in `$str1` is present in `$str2`, for example `'அடைமானம்'` is present in `$str2`, I want to replace the 
`{"id":"3","name":"அடைமானம் ","parent":"1","tooltip":"   ","color":"#FF0000"}` from `$str1` with 3rd set.

`$str1` and `$str2` in pastebin:

https://pastebin.com/11p8U71x

```
           <?php
           $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","data");       

            if (mysqli_connect_errno())                
              {
              echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
              }
             $name='அடகு';
            //To get the Main json
            $sql="SELECT * FROM mytab where value='$name' ";

            $r = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                    $data = array();

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
                      $data[] = $row;
                    }
            $nestedArray = array();
            foreach($data as $itemData){

              $nestedArrayItem['id'] = $itemData['id'];
                $nestedArrayItem['name'] = $itemData['name'];
                $nestedArrayItem['parent'] = $itemData['parent'];
              $nestedArrayItem['tooltip'] = $itemData['tooltip'];
                 $nestedArrayItem['color'] = $itemData['color'];
            $nestedArrayItem['children'] = array();
            insertIntoNestedArrayyy($nestedArray, $nestedArrayItem);
            }
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
                $jj=(array_remove_empty($nestedArray));
            $json=json_encode($jj,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

            echo "MAIN json:"."\n". $json;      

         echo "\n";
          echo "CHILD AND SUBCHILD JSON:"."\n";
            foreach($nestedArray as $r){
          foreach($r['children'] as $k){
          $w= $k['name'];
            //To get the subchild
         $sq="SELECT * FROM mytab where value='$w' ";
           $rr = mysqli_query($conn,$sq);
                    $dataa = array();

                    while($roww = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rr)) {
                      $dataa[] = $roww;
                    }

              $nestedArray = array();
            foreach($dataa as $itemData){
              $nestedArrayItem['id'] = $itemData['id'];
                $nestedArrayItem['name'] = $itemData['name'];
                $nestedArrayItem['parent'] = $itemData['parent'];
              $nestedArrayItem['tooltip'] = $itemData['tooltip'];
                 $nestedArrayItem['color'] = $itemData['color'];
                $nestedArrayItem['children'] = array();
                insertIntoNestedArrayyy($nestedArray, $nestedArrayItem);
             }
        $nestedArray=(array_remove_empty($nestedArray));
                    $c1= json_encode($nestedArray,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
             $c1 = substr($c1, 1, -1);
           // $c1=str_replace("[]"," ",$c1);

           echo $c1;

            foreach($nestedArray as $r){
        foreach($r['children'] as $k){
        $w= $k['name'];
        //To get the sub-subchild
        $sql="SELECT * FROM mytab where value='$w' ";
                    $rr = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                    $dataa = array();

                    while($roww = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rr)) {
                        if($roww >0){
                      $dataa[] = $roww;
                }}

               $nestedArray = array();
            foreach($dataa as $itemData){
              $nestedArrayItem['id'] = $itemData['id'];
                $nestedArrayItem['name'] = $itemData['name'];
                $nestedArrayItem['parent'] = $itemData['parent'];
              $nestedArrayItem['tooltip'] = $itemData['tooltip'];
                 $nestedArrayItem['color'] = $itemData['color'];
                $nestedArrayItem['children'] = array();
                insertIntoNestedArrayyy($nestedArray, $nestedArrayItem);
              }
        $nestedArray=(array_remove_empty($nestedArray));
                    $c2= json_encode($nestedArray,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
                    $c2=str_replace("[]"," ",$c2);

            echo $c2."\n";
              }


                 }

         }
          }
          function buildtt($src_arr, $parent_id = 0, $tree = array())
            {
                foreach($src_arr as $idx => $roww)
                {
                    if($roww['parent'] == $parent_id)
                    {
                        foreach($roww as $k => $v)
                            $tree[$roww['id']][$k] = $v;
                        unset($src_arr[$idx]);
            $tree[$roww['id']]['children'] = buildtt($src_arr, $roww['id']);
                    }
                }
                ksort($tree);
                return $tree;
            }
             function array_remove_empty($haystack)
            {
                foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
                    if (is_array($value)) {
                    $haystack[$key] = array_remove_empty($haystack[$key]);
                    }

                    if (empty($haystack[$key])) {
                        unset($haystack[$key]);
                    }
                }

                return $haystack;
            }
            function insertIntoNestedArrayyy(&$array, $searchItem){

                if($searchItem['parent'] == 0){
                    array_push($array, $searchItem);
                    return;
                }
                if(empty($array)){ return; }
             array_walk($array, function(&$item, $key, $searchItem){
                if($item['id'] == $searchItem['parent']){
                        array_push($item['children'], $searchItem);
                        return;
                    }
                    insertIntoNestedArrayyy($item['children'], $searchItem);
            }, $searchItem);
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Why not do the string replacement where you assign values to the array before encoding the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

you can decode json to array and merge it with replacing data where keys are duplicate

```
$str1Json=json_decode($str1, true);
$str2Json=json_decode($str2, true);
$output = array_merge_recusrsive($str1Json, $str2Json);
```

http://php.net/array_merge_recusrsive

http://php.net/json_decode

Comment: since i have more than one set of json in $str2.i got  Warning: array_merge_recursive(): Argument #2 is not an array ..i tested with one json in the $str2...this is what i got -https://pastebin.com/iWMWUj7M

Comment: check what $j1 and $j2 is returning. second json_decode() most probably failing. var_dump() the values and make sure $str1 is valid json string